# How to execute another page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a page that I need to call from another page more that one time. The important thing is to execute the Page_Load method. the first page have this code (The first page name is Call.aspx):

```
  Dim objWebClient As New WebClient
                        objWebClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")
                        Dim objStream As Stream = objWebClient.OpenRead("D:\confirm.aspx")
                        Dim objSR As New System.IO.StreamReader(objStream)
                        objWebClient.Dispose()
                        objStream.Dispose()
```

This should call the other page. It does not execute the other page. I have the following code to make sure that the confirm page is executed:

```
 Dim objWrite As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\aa.txt")
        objWrite.WriteLine("Hello")
        objWrite.Close()
```

But there is no output. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `HttpServerUtility.Execute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is this doing?:

```
objWebClient.OpenRead("D:\confirm.aspx")
```

Is `D:\` a reference to a web address?  It looks like you're just calling the file itself, which isn't going to have the effect you're looking for.  (Ignoring for a moment the file residing in the root of a drive...)

ASPX pages aren't executable in and of themselves.  A web server (IIS, usually) has to handle the requests for them and pass those requests through the .NET runtime, etc., in order to handle the server-side processing.  The file itself is just text, it has no internal means to interpret server-side code.  That's what a web server is for.

In order to make a web request to a web resource (a page, or any other web resource), you need to use a web URL.  Something like: `http://localhost/confirm.aspx`  So that page will need to be served somewhere by a web server.

**More to the point, however**, is the fact that you *shouldn't* have to do this.  If code needs to be shared by two pages, that code should be extracted into a shared component.  A "page" should never have to "call another page" (unless they're on completely separate servers and you're going for more of a SOA approach).  Both pages should call a single shared component (a class, usually, maybe in its own assembly or just in the web project that has the pages).

Business logic doesn't go in pages.  Only UI goes in pages.  Shared business logic goes in business classes.

Comment: I have a private server so I call these command with the physical path

Comment: @amrswalha: And does that work for you?  It doesn't matter if your server is "private" or not.  What matters is that in order to execute a web resource you need to make a call to a web server.  That server can be the local host, the HTTP protocol doesn't care either way.  But a web server of some kind needs to be involved to invoke the ASP.NET server components which interpret the code.  Otherwise you're just trying to execute a text file.

Comment: You are 100% correct. But do you think I could Insert the same code in a scheduled task?

Comment: @amrswalha: You can execute business logic in any application context you'd like.  A web application, a console application (scheduled to run through some task scheduling tool), a Windows service, a client application, etc.  It all depends on what you're actually trying to do and, architecturally, what solution makes the most sense.  But to your question, yes, if you create a shared component in .NET (perhaps in its own project/assembly), then multiple projects of any type can reference that code.

Comment: Thanks very much for your great support.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be interested in [HttpServerUtility.Execute()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb04e8f7.aspx).